# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to harvest twitter data with respect to Latitude and Longitude but I happen to get error.

I am trying to avoid the tweet count limit and also the timing limit of scraping.

Code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

ckey = 'XYZ'
csecret = 'XYZ'
atoken = 'XYZ'
asecret = 'XYZ'

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret, 'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print " Scraping data now" # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms  q='hello'
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,geocode="55.0000,4.0000,1000km",since= '2016-06-27',until='2016-06-28',lang='en',count=100)
    results=[]
    for item in cursor.items(1000): # Remove the limit to 1000
            results.append(item)

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Language'] = [tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]
    #DataSet['UserWhoRetweeted'] = [i for i in users_retweeted]

    return DataSet

DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
DataSet.to_csv('Belgium_27.csv',index=False)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CS.py", line 23, in <module>
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit'
```

What changes are to be made in order to solve the error and harvest the tweets?

**Edit One**: After `tweepy` upgrade I get the following warning and the program terminates automatically

```
Scraping data now
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

**Edit Two:** After changing the indentation on write statements in the code. The program executes but returns only empty `CSV`.

Comment: What's your tweepy version?

Comment: @user2357112 I am not able to find the version of tweepy, My python version is 2.7

Comment: @user2357112 It was 2.2.1 version previously and just now I have upgraded it to 3.5.0

Comment: 2.2.1 didn't have `wait_on_rate_limit`. Your upgrade to 3.5.0 should resolve this issue.

Comment: @user2357112 After upgrade when I run the program I get the following warning and the program terminates

Comment: Well, your program isn't programmed to do anything with that data it's scraping. Check the indentation on those last few lines.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes changed and that gives me emtpy file with only header.  :(

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine for me after removing `wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True`.

There is no such argument mentioned in docs:

> class tweepy.API(auth=None, *, cache=None, host='api.twitter.com', parser=None, proxy=None, retry_count=0, retry_delay=0, retry_errors=None, timeout=60, upload_host='upload.twitter.com', user_agent=None, wait_on_rate_limit=False)

See [docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time


ckey = '***'
csecret = '***'
atoken = '***'
asecret = '***'

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret, 'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])

api = tweepy.API(auth)
if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print ("Scraping data now") # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms  q='hello'
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="truffles", result_type="new", geocode="55.0000,4.0000,1000km",lang='en',count=100)
    results=[]
    for item in cursor.items(1000): # Remove the limit to 1000
            results.append(item)

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Language'] = [tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]
    #DataSet['UserWhoRetweeted'] = [i for i in users_retweeted]

    return DataSet

DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
DataSet.to_csv('Belgium_27.csv',index=False)
```

You had specified a time period however that seems to no longer be available for tweepy.

**result type**
Specifies what type of search results you would prefer to receive. The current default is "mixed." Valid values include:

- mixed : include both popular and real time results in the response
- recent : return only the most recent results in the response
- popular: return only the most popular results in the response count
  |count|    until Returns tweets created before the given date. Date
  should be    formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.

**Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day** limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week. since_id |since_id|
There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occurred since the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available. max_id |max_id| include_entities|include_entities|