# Unexpected error argument during “wait_on_rate_limit” in a Python script that uses Tweepy

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I worked with this twitter python script a few month ago, and it was working. I don't know what I may have accidentally changed, but I now have an error message:

```
line 32, in <module> api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True) TypeError: __init__() got an
```

unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit'

error when running this script.

Could someone help me understand why? Thanks a lot!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim: tabstop=4 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4


import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import getopt
import json
import time
import os
import sys

# Vecteurs d'accreditation a renseigner
# apres creation dans le gestionnaire d'applications Twitter 
# cf : https://apps.twitter.com/
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

# Constantes
maxTweets = 10000000   # Nombre de tweet max a recuperer
tw_block_size = 100    # Nombre de Tweet par requete
sinceId = None         # Recuperation des tweets du plus recent au plus ancien

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

def usage():
    """
    Display usage
    """
    sys.stderr.write( "Usage: collect.py -s <hashtag> | --search=<hashtag>\n"+
                      "                 [-o <output-dir> | --output-dir=<output-dir>]\n"+
                      "                 [-m <max-id> | --maxid=<max-id>]\n")

def main(argv):
    """
    Collecte des tweets associe a un hashtag.
    """
    tweetCount = 0
    search_query = None
    max_id = -1L
    output_dir = "."

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "ho:s:m:", ["help","output-dir=","search=","maxid="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(1)

    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit(0)
        if o in ("-s", "--search" ):
            search_query = a
        if o in ("-o", "--output-dir" ):
            output_dir = a
        if o in ("-m", "--maxid" ):
            max_id = long(a)

    if not search_query:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    print("Parametres de la collecte :")
    print(" - Hashtag    : {0}".format(search_query))
    print(" - Repertoire : {0}".format(output_dir))
    print(" - Max ID     : {0}".format(max_id))
    print("")

    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    
    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
         try:
             if (max_id <= 0):
                 if (not sinceId):
                     new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size)
                 else:
                     new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, since_id=sinceId)
    
             else:
                 if (not sinceId):
                     new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, max_id=str(max_id - 1))
                 else:
                     new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, max_id=str(max_id - 1), since_id=sinceId)
    
             if not new_tweets:
                 print("Collecte terminee.")
                 break
             for tweet in new_tweets:
                 day = tweet.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                 with open( "%s/%s_tweets.json" % (output_dir, day), 'a') as f:
                     f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
                     f.write('\n')
             tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
             print("{0} tweets téléchargés".format(tweetCount))
             max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
         except tweepy.TweepError as e:
             print("Une erreur est intervenue. Pour poursuivre le processus de collecte, relancer la commande suivante :")
             print("python collect.py -s \"{0}\" -o \"{1}\" -m \"{2}\"".format(search_query, output_dir, max_id))
             print("")
             print("Error : " + str(e))
             break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works fine for me with Python 2.7.15 and Tweepy 3.7.0, make sure you are using the latest version of Tweepy. Your error might be related to an older version of Tweepy as stated here: [TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111125/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-wait-on-rate-limit)

To check your version of Tweepy: `pip show tweepy`, to upgrade: `pip install tweepy --upgrade`

Please note that the standard search API won't return statuses older than 10 days. The official Twitter API documentation mentions this: "Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit" even though the practical limit I experience is 10 days. To go beyond this limit, you could use a web scraper like https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper which doesn't make use of the official API at all.

Comment: Praise be the lord! I had install a tweepy-utils package that changed the version of tweepy. Upgrade... and it worked again. Thank you so much, and thanks again for the scrapper GitHub project!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? This is how it's done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thank you.